# Book about a girl who swung on a swing set so hard she turned upside down

Tags: story-identification

In it a girl swung on a swing set so hard she went over the top bar.  As a result she was permanently upside down or gravity was up for her instead of down.  To counteract the effect she and her friends had to get a frog and/or tadpoles and some jars filled with some sort of liquid and perform some sort of ritual.

I read this book in the late 70's or early 80's in Midwestern United States.

Comment: When were you a teen (i.e. whenabouts did you read the book)? What language was it written in? Was it a novel or short story? Any details can be helpful :-)

Comment: Good points.  It was in the late 70's or early 80's in Midwestern United States.

Comment: Huh.  Seems like a good fit for [*Toots Underground*](http://www.whatsthatbook.com/?xq=14742) by Carol Hughes, but that was published in 2001.

Comment: What a silly premise. Everybody knows that if you go over the top bar of the swing, you turn inside-out!

Comment: I was hoping someone else was going to mention Inside-Out Boy. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oa46mnTDiVQ

Answer (score 5):

[Witch In The House](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0590000934) by Ruth Chew

> Laura and Jane have a new friend...a friend who eats glass and can sit
>   on the ceiling!
>
> Laura stared hard at her. "You're a witch!" "Now, now. Don't start
>   using bad names," the old woman said. "We were just getting to be
>   friends." "But you are a witch, aren't you?" Laura persisted.

From [the book](https://books.google.com/books?id=fGxQCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT84&lpg=PT84&dq=ruth%20chew%20witch%20swingset&source=bl&ots=iZDOMMF2gE&sig=HycKBRSB8tfu9vlBnAseg_ZnETc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ2YOpu9fcAhWQEXwKHV1fAOYQ6AEwDXoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=ruth%20chew%20witch%20swingset&f=false):

> Sally smiled. "I just remembered something," she said.
>   "What is it?" Jane asked.
>   "How I turned upside down."
>   "How?" Laura wanted to know.
>   "I swung over the top bar of the swing set. Don't ever do it." ....

Comment: Just to comment, David, but if you ever come back, you can accept your own answer.